# MembershipService not initialized

Tags: c#, membership-provider

following some example from Microsoft I created my custom MembershipProvider in my MVC application as

```
if (MembershipService == null) { MembershipService = new AccountMembershipService(new FcMembershipProvider()); }
```

and the web.config is configured as

```
<membership defaultProvider="FcMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
  <providers>
    <clear />

    <add
      name="FcMembershipProvider"
      type="Fc.Web.WebAppMVC.Models.FcMembershipProvider"
      connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
      enablePasswordRetrieval="true"
      enablePasswordReset="true"
      applicationName="FcWebMVC"
      requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"
      writeExceptionsToEventLog="false" />

  </providers>
</membership>
```

Problem is the Initialize method is not automatically called. any hint?

Thx

Comment: Did you run the asp.net tool that installs the structures on the database?

Comment: It jas just the example. No I haven't run any tool because I am coding everything from ground up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to get hold of your membership provider using the static `Membership.Provider` like so:

```
if (MembershipService == null) { MembershipService = new AccountMembershipService((FcMembershipProvider)Membership.Provider); }
```

(I put a cast in there which you may not need depending on what `AccoundMembershipService` is expecting.)  This way ASP .NET's membership system should initialize it for you.

Comment: You have been that fast I cannot even accept your answer because SO does not want to!!! Allow 5 minutes!

Answer (score 0):

what is the class that implements "MembershipProvider" class ? beacause in your config file it's "FcMembershipProvider" and in the code it's AccountMembershipService.

I created a custom membership provider, I only implemented the "MembershipProvider" class, and added the config like you've done, I think you dont have to add code.